# If statement with multiple conditions and empty values

Tags: python, pandas

This should be a simple one.

I want to create a new column that is populated with Y and N, based on certain conditions:

If a value from `id` in `df1` exists in `id` in `df2`, return Y, else N.
If a value in `id` in `df1` is NaN, return N. (id column is numeric)

What I have is:

```
df1['new_col']=df1['id'].isin(df2['id']).replace({False: 'N', True:'Y'})
```

which is fine, except that I also get a Y for empty values, but I want a N for NaN values.

So I've tried these but it's not working:

```
df1['new_col']=df1['new_col'].apply(lambda x: 'N' if pd.isnull(x)==True else x['new_col'])
```

or

```
def ss_am(x):
    if x['id'].isin(df2['id']):
        return 'Y'
    if x['id']==pd.isnull(x):
        return 'N'
    else:
        return 'N'
    
df['new_col']=df.apply(ss_am, 1)
```

exapmle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is about a Pandas DataFrame, correct? It helps to point that out, and tag the question with `pandas`. Python is not exclusively Pandas.

Comment: Please show an actual example dataframe (relatively short, as it's an example), and the expected result. That makes it easier to deduce what you want, as there may be another way of doing this that is even easier.

Comment: What is "blank" for the 'id' here? `None`, `NaN` or an empty string, `''`. Or even a string with only spaces?

Comment: What type of values (and possible range) are 'id'?

Comment: edited, thanks for pointing all of this out

Comment: Why you dont use join in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'id' column contains strings (since I don't see NaN in the output) and the value is always > 0,

```
df1['new_col'] = df1['id'].replace('', '-1').isin(df2['id']).replace({False: 'N', True:'Y'})
```

can work. That temporarily substitutes '-1' for the blanks, which df2 is very unlikely to have.

If the blanks are NaNs instead (and id are integers/floats), you can use `fillna()` with a suitable value:

```
df1['new_col'] = df1['id'].fillna(-1).isin(df2['id']).replace({False: 'N', True:'Y'})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by merging 2 df:

```
# Create expected value in df2
df2['new_col'] = 'y'
# Merge 2 dfs 
output_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=["id"] )
# Fill missing values
output_df['new_col'].fillna('n', inplace=True)
```